# Unrecognized selector in NSObject

Tags: ios, nsobject, unrecognized-selector

I have a ViewController that instantiate the Trophy class that it does this:

```
#import "Trophy.h"
#import "WATrophiesViewController.h"

@implementation Trophy


-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame trophyName:(NSString *)trophyName trophyDesc:(NSString *)trophyDesc imageName:(NSString *)imageName viewController:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        self.trophyName = trophyName;
        self.trophyDesc = trophyDesc;
        self.trophyImage = imageName;
        self.controller = controller;
    }
    return self;
}

-(UIView *)drawView
{
    // Imposto lo sfondo del frame della view
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"container"]];

    // Imposto l'immagine del trofeo
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.trophyImage]];
    CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 138.0f, 191.0f);
    image.frame = imageFrame;

    // La disegno
    [self.view addSubview:image];

    // Imposto il titolo del trofeo
    UILabel *titolo = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140.0f, 20.0f, 260.0f, 90.0f)];
    titolo.text = self.trophyName;
    titolo.numberOfLines = 0;
    titolo.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    titolo.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Lo disegno
    [self.view addSubview:titolo];

    // Imposto la parte per lo share
    UIView *shareDiv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140.0f, 130.0f, 300.0f, 140.0f)];
    UILabel *share = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 30.0f)];
    share.text = @"SHARE";
    share.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [shareDiv addSubview:share];
    UIButton *twitter = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 30.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)];
    [twitter setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tw-iphone"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [twitter addTarget:self action:@selector(twitter:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [shareDiv addSubview:twitter];

    UIButton *fb = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0f, 30.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)];
    [fb setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fb-iphone"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [fb addTarget:self action:@selector(fb:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [shareDiv addSubview:fb];


    [self.view addSubview:shareDiv];

    return self.view;
}

-(void)twitter:(id)sender
{

}
-(void)fb:(id)sender
{

}
@end
```

But when I tap on one of these two buttons errors occur. Why? This is the error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM fb:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e9e7d0'

EDIT:
That's the stack trace

```
2014-06-18 14:02:55.953 Wikitude Approx[1027:60b] (
0   Wikitude Approx                     0x000f5c57 -[Trophy drawView] + 1446
1   Wikitude Approx                     0x000f48c9 -[WATrophiesViewController viewDidLoad] + 1352
2   UIKit                               0x330f2a53 <redacted> + 518
3   UIKit                               0x3319d30d <redacted> + 32
4   UIKit                               0x3319d223 <redacted> + 230
5   UIKit                               0x3319c801 <redacted> + 80
6   UIKit                               0x3319c529 <redacted> + 572
7   UIKit                               0x3319c299 <redacted> + 44
8   UIKit                               0x3319c231 <redacted> + 184
9   UIKit                               0x330ee305 <redacted> + 380
10  QuartzCore                          0x32d6a31b <redacted> + 142
11  QuartzCore                          0x32d65b3f <redacted> + 350
12  QuartzCore                          0x32d659d1 <redacted> + 16
13  QuartzCore                          0x32d653e5 <redacted> + 228
14  QuartzCore                          0x32d651f7 <redacted> + 314
15  UIKit                               0x330e6a27 <redacted> + 126
16  CoreFoundation                      0x3088a039 <redacted> + 20
17  CoreFoundation                      0x308879c7 <redacted> + 286
18  CoreFoundation                      0x30887d13 <redacted> + 738
19  CoreFoundation                      0x307f2769 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
20  CoreFoundation                      0x307f254b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
21  GraphicsServices                    0x3575f6d3 GSEventRunModal + 138
22  UIKit                               0x33151891 UIApplicationMain + 1136
23  Wikitude Approx                     0x000f23e1 main + 116
24  libdyld.dylib                       0x3b553ab7 <redacted> + 2
```

)

That is how I use the class

```
self.scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(414.0f, 3000.0f);

// Creo il trofeo della prima visita
Trophy *trofeoPrimaVisita = [[Trophy alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 414.0f, 228.0f) trophyName:@"Hai lanciato per la prima volta l'applicazione" trophyDesc:@"Ho lanciato per la prima volta l'applicazione Hermes" imageName:@"trofeoaudio-guida-5" viewController:self];
UIView *trofeoView = [trofeoPrimaVisita drawView];
[self.scroll addSubview:trofeoView];
```

Comment: I don't think the error is in the code you posted.  Post the stacktrace please.

Comment: Looks like your instantiated Trophy object has been released, you need to keep a strong reference to it.

Comment: `NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM fb:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e9e7d0` for whatever reason the method `fb` is called on a `NSMutableArray` which of course does not implement the method `fb`

Comment: What does `WATrophiesViewController` do with the view that you return from `drawView`?  Also, what is the parent class of `Trophy`?

Comment: Hi Phillip I updated the first post

Comment: @LucaD just for the sake of it, can you rename UIButton *fb to UIButton *fbBtn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a strong reference to `trofeoPrimaVisita` as a property of the caller instead of having is as a local variable.

I assume you're using ARC and the object (`Trophy`) that implements `fb:` has been released by the time the button is tapped.

Comment: I thought about it, but then I have to generate more than one Trophy object in WATrophiesViewController, so I cannot do this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "have to generate" but you need the object to be strongly referenced if you want to avoid the crash.  If you need many of these, use an array or set or dictionary…whatever makes sense.

Comment: I use a for to instantiate and generate X trophy views, so if I declare a strong property, this will be filled with the last object.

Comment: Then make the strong property an array and add the `Trophy` objects to that.  The other option would be to get rid of `Trophy` entirely and put the button handlers and view creation logic into the controller that ends up showing the views.

Comment: thanks, I solved with a NSMutableArray with a strong reference where I added all the Trophy objects.

Answer (score -2):

just remove the colon u put after method name in selector. like replace `@selector(fb:)` with `@selector(fb)`. I hope this help :)